# System watcher in VB.net or C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, system, uac

I want to write a simple program, which should inform me before any files getting open (like as User account control in Windows Vista or Windows 7). I came to know that all antiviruses use this technique to detect viruses before they are affecting the system. My program must ask me as "Are you allow this file to run?" and allow it if I allow otherwise terminate the file. Please help me and I kindly expect the sample code in VB.Net or C#.Net.

Please accept my apologize for my poor language and thanks in advance.

Comment: A very *simple* program, indeed.

Comment: Are you trying to create UAC? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/user-account-control

Comment: Download Process Monitor then see how many file open operations happen per second. Are you sure you want to click OK that many times?

Comment: @dotalchemy: What, you can't click that fast?

Comment: @Mehrdad - No, I'd ask SO on how to write a C# app which would automatically click OK on the popups. How would I do that? I expect code samples :)

Comment: @dotalchemy: Learn to click at over 9000 Hz like a pro. :P

Comment: lol I bet I can click faster than you! HA.... void CauseRSI() for (int i =0; i < 9000; i++); {SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");}

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in VB.NET or C#, without the help of external code.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, do you mean This is not possible in VB.NET or C#, without the help of external code *such as unmanaged API's and etc*

Comment: @Jeremy: No, I mean it is not possible to *block* the opening of a file from .NET, *period*. To do that you'd need a file system filter driver, written in C.

Answer (score 1):

You want to hook into Process Monitor... here is the code you will need to do that: [Easy Hook into ProcessMonitor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/EasyHook64.aspx)

> To prove that EasyHook really makes
>   hooking simple, look at the following
>   demo application, which will log all
>   file accesses from a given process.